# Analytics Site Speed Sample Rate

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm tracking traffic on my site, more or less about 100 visit for day, but the siteSpeed shows something every 3/4 days.
I have already put this code in my header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

But it didn't change anything.
Someone can tell me how i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

`ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});`

Move `siteSpeedSampleRate` parameter to first ga('create') line and delete whole second line. GA won't create second tracker with this same (default) name.